# Weird natural numbers function problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, recurrence-relations, periodic-functions, natural-numbers

So I came across with the following problem, of a Brazilian elementary number theory book, which did not came with the resolutions:
"Let $f:\Bbb N^{*} \to \Bbb N^{*}$ a function such that $f(a)=f(1995)$, $f(a+1)=f(1996)$,
$f(a+2)=f(1997)$ and $$f(a+n)=\frac{f(n)-1}{f(n)+1}$$
for $a∈\Bbb N$. Find the least possible value of $a$."
I tried many calculations, but the result was always circular, and I'd like to see what you guys would try.
I appreciate your help!

Comment: The last equality for all $n\in\Bbb N^*$ or only for $n>2$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The problem didn't specified that, but I try to solve it considering that the relation holds for $n \geq 1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'd like to see your try, if possible, because I found this problem really misleading.

Comment: $\frac{f(n) - 1}{f(n)+1}$ is a natural number only when $f(n)=1$

Comment: Assume $$f(a+n)=\frac{f(n)-1}{f(n)+1}\qquad\text{ for all }n\in S.$$
Let $n\in S$. As $f(a+n)-1$ is an integer, $f(n)+1$ must be a divisor of  $2$, i.e., $f(n)=1$ and $f(a+n)=0$. It follows that $a+n\notin S$ for $n\in S$. In articular, $S$ cannot be all of $\Bbb N$ or of the form $\{\,n\in\Bbb N^*\mid n>c\,\}$.

Comment: So you guys think that the construction of the problem makes it impossible to solve?

Comment: Note first that $f(n)$ can never be odd, since if $f(n)=2k+1$, $k\ge0$, then
$$f(a+n)=\frac{f(n)-1}{f(n)+1}=\frac{2k+1-1}{2k+1+1}=\frac{k}{k+1}$$
So $f(n)=2k$. Then 
$$f(a+n)=\frac{f(n)-1}{f(n)+1}=\frac{2k-1}{2k+1}$$
But then the denominator is bigger than the numerator, and so $f(a+n)$ is not an integer.